# Rendering Audio Stream from RTSP server

Tags: rtsp, ms-media-foundation

i have an  RTSP server which is re-streaming the A/V stream from the camera to clients.

Client side we are using MF to play the stream.

I can successfully play the video but not able to play the audio from the server. However when i use vlc to play, it can play both A/V.

Currently i am implementing IMFMediaStream and have created my customize media stream. I have also created a separate IMFStreamDescriptor for audio and added all the required attributes. When i run , everything goes fine but my RequestSample method never gets called.

Please let me know if i am doing it wrong or if there is any other way to play the audio in MF.

Thanks,

Prateek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Media Foundation support for RTSP is limited to a small number of payload formats. VLC supports more (AFAIR through Live555 library). Most likely, your payload is not supported in Media Foundation.